# AngularJs : Use length of array filter in controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Hey i have problem i will using my length array filter in my controller ,the length value is visable in html view but i will use this value in controller

```
<div ui-tree id="tree-root">
     <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="product.versions.tree" >
       <li ng-repeat="node in (test=(product.versions.tree | filter:search.query))"  ui-tree-node collapsed='collpsed' ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'" ></li>
 <p>{{test.length}}</p>
    </ol>
```

Comment: the question is not at all clear

Comment: i will use value test  length in controller ,he didn't work with  fonction $watch